# How can you have $\frac{DA^\mu}{d\tau}$?

Tags: general-relativity, notation, tensor-calculus, differentiation

If a covariant derivative is given by: 
$$D_\nu A^\mu=\partial_\nu A^\mu +\Gamma^\mu_{\nu \lambda} A^{\lambda}$$
Then how does $\frac{DA^\mu}{d\tau}$ make any sense? Since there are no 'differentials' in $D_\nu$ for $d\tau$ to act on.

**Clarification**

The parameter $\tau$ can be seen as an arbitrary parameter, although $\tau$ is often used for proper time (interpreting as either arbitrary or proper time does not change the question). I came across the expression $\frac{D A^\mu}{d\tau}$ when looking at parallel transports, but it is also used in the geodesic equation in general relativity and probably a lot of other places to.

Comment: While clear to most people familiar with the topic, it would improve the question to state in which context $\frac{DA^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\tau}$ arises, and that $\tau$ denotes.

Comment: A way to think about this: $\partial_\mu:=\partial/\partial x^\mu$ and $\mathrm{D}_\mu:=\mathrm{D}/\partial x^\mu$. Then consider the relationship $\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}\tau=\dot x^\mu\partial_\mu$. Try to find the analogy with $\mathrm{D}/\mathrm{d}\tau$.

Comment: While we're on the topic of notation, you should be aware that 99% of GR literature uses $\nabla$ for the covariant derivative in your first equation, not $D$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a covariant derivative along a world line (if you would not consider a world line the proper time $\tau$ would not make any sense).

So you consider a curve in space time parametrized in dependence of the proper time $x^\mu(\tau)$. Then you have:

$$\frac{DA^\mu}{d\tau} = \frac{\partial A^{\mu}\big(x(\tau)\big)}{\partial \tau} + \Gamma^\mu_{\nu\lambda} A^\nu \dot x^\lambda = \dot x^\lambda A^\mu_{,\lambda} + \Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu\lambda} A^\nu \dot x^\lambda = \dot x^\lambda A^\mu_{;\lambda}.$$

For more details see Wikipedia on [Covariant Derivative Along a Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative#Derivative_along_curve) and on the [Levi-Civita connection along the curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection#Derivative_along_curve). (These articles use an index free notation, not the Ricci calculus usually employed by physicists).

When you are doing things rigorously (i.e. if you are doing mathematics) the connection along a curve only requires the values a vector field along the curve and then therefore is more general than the expression $\dot x^\nu A^\mu_{;\nu}$ (which requires the vector field on an open set which contains the curve).

On a side note, this notion also occurs in the well known gedesic equation:
$$ \frac{D \dot x^\mu}{D\tau} = 0 = \ddot x^\mu + \Gamma^\mu_{\lambda\nu} \dot x^\lambda \dot x^\nu.$$
(With the difference, that $\dot x^\mu$ is a function of $\tau$ not of $x^\mu(\tau)$).

Comment: Is there any way to determine the expression for $\frac{DA^{\mu}}{d\tau}$ from the expression for $D_\nu A^{\mu}$ or are do they have no link. (sorry if you explain this in your answer, and I have misunderstood)

Comment: @Joseph: If you look closely at the expression in the answer, you'll see that $\frac{\mathrm{D}A^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\tau} = \dot{x}^\nu\mathrm{D}_\nu A^\mu $ (SebastianRiese wrote $A^\mu_{;\lambda}$ for $D_\lambda A^\mu$).

Comment: @ACuriousMind Ok, I think I have got it now, is this correct: $\frac{DA^{\mu}}{d\tau}\equiv \nabla_{\vec V} \vec A$ where $\vec V$ is the tangent to some curve $\vec r(\tau)$

Comment: @Joseph Yes, that is correct.