# What is the difference between $\frac{DA^\mu}{D\lambda}$ and $\frac{DA^\mu}{d\lambda}$?

Tags: general-relativity, notation, differentiation

I earlier asked this question [How can you have $\frac{DA^\mu}{d\tau}$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206085/how-can-you-have-fracda-mud-tau) I am now wondering:

What is the difference between $\frac{DA^\mu}{D\lambda}$ and $\frac{DA^\mu}{d\lambda}$?

In the linked question the answer and comments explain what $\frac{DA^\mu}{d\lambda}$ and some research tells me that $\frac{DA^\mu}{D\lambda}$ is called the intrinsic or total derivative. The forms of the two derivatives seem to be the same though, if this is the case why the use of different notation?

Comment: You need to give references for where and in which contexts such notation appears! Notation is not standardized across references and you cannot expect people to conclude what notation means without looking at its source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{DA^\mu}{D\lambda}=\frac{DA^\mu}{d\lambda}$ are two notations for the same object.